# Android: Refining zoomable Picture

Tags: android, bitmap, out-of-memory, zooming

I've been struggling for a long time with large images that are able to zoom. I am loading some picture from the network that can have very variable size: it might go from 0.5MP up to 10MP. Simply loading one to a bitmap can produce application crash because of OOM exception. But details are very important so I want the user to be able to zoom on them such that full quality is maintained (so the picture should refine itself during zooming). I don't find a proper way to do this. I've used the `TouchImageView` library, but it doesn't manage large pictures at all. If I first down sample my picture with the `inSampleSize` parameter of the `BitmapFactory`, I lose the quality definitively. I don't want to code a whole new zooming tool, as it is already implemented on every android phone in the default Gallery app. There has to be a way to use this kind of tool, and simply display a large image that is able to zoom, right?

Comment: Did you look into the Gallery app source?

Comment: I did but it is a very complex application and it is hard to extract the part I need for zooming. There should be a simpler solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Have you tried [PhotoView](https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView)?
2. You could also do it with `loadUrl(String)` of standard [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) which should handle big images too. WebView has built-in zoom controls.

Comment: PhotoView is a very nice project, but from what I understood it only manages zooming on a classical ImageView, which is exactly the same as ToucheImageView. If the picture is to large, you have to down sample it first or it won't work. It's what I'm trying to avoid!

Comment: Then try to load the image with `loadUrl(String)` of standard `android.webkit.WebView` as I suggested. So far I haven't seen any big images crashing by OOM when using it.

Comment: `WebView` works like a charm! I would never have thought using it to display a local image! I don't understand why these options are not built in `ImageView`. It would be 1000% more intuitive. Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 0):

[BitmapRegionDecoder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapRegionDecoder.html)(added in 2.3.3) may work. But I've not tried it.
It seems that the implementation in Gallery is OpenGL, there is no way to use it simply.

Comment: I know about `BitmapRegionDecoder`, but it would imply to re-implement entirely the pinch and zoom mechanism, which makes no sense in a high level programming framework like Android! I would recommend using `WebView`!